# SQLite3 SUM by date

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 with Python, and I have some data that looks roughly similar to this:

| Date | Parent ID | Child ID | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Day1 | 1 | A | 5 |
| Day1 | 1 | B | 10 |
| Day1 | 2 | C | 20 |
| Day2 | 1 | A | 10 |
| Day2 | 1 | B | 15 |
| Day2 | 2 | C | 30 |

I'm trying to create a view that would show me this:

| Date | Parent ID | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Day1 | 1 | 15 |
| Day1 | 2 | 20 |
| Day2 | 1 | 25 |
| Day2 | 2 | 30 |

I've tried summing with a GROUP BY but am currently only able to produce this:

| Date | Parent ID | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Day1 | 1 | 40 |
| Day1 | 2 | 50 |
| Day2 | 1 | 40 |
| Day2 | 2 | 50 |

The sum function seems to be summing all data used in the parent class regardless of date-related group-by statements. How would I make sure that the points are summed by day, rather than just totally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group by Date, ParentID` seems to work fine:

```
select Date, ParentID, sum(Points) as Points
from table_name
group by Date, ParentID;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ec465fde0e9f253d69266ecdb723faf3)

To create a view:

```
create view sumPoints as
select Date, ParentID, sum(Points) as Points
from table_name
group by Date, ParentID;
```

Comment: Thank you, you're correct. The actual view creation was a fair bit more complex and I realised (after your answer) that I'd left out a grouping field in a nested select 